# OpenApi documentation with spring-doc in combination with ResponseBodyAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springfox, springdoc

I have a simple rest API and I am testing springdoc swagger documentation.
The rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('create:user')")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> create(final @RequestBody @Valid CreateUserCommand command) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(userService.create(command));
    }
}
```

Then I wrap all the API response objects in a ResponseControllerAdvice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(final @NotNull MethodParameter returnType,
                            final @NotNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(final Object body,
                                  final @NotNull MethodParameter returnType,
                                  final @NotNull MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  final @NotNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  final @NotNull ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  final @NotNull ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body instanceof ResponseEnvelope || body instanceof Resource) {
            return body;
        }
        if (body instanceof final ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity) {
            response.setStatusCode(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        }
        return ResponseEnvelope.builder().success(true).result(body).build();
    }
```

But I am struggling to find a way to make Springdoc take into consideration this **ResponseEnvelope** wrapper object. Any ideas?

using Spring boot 2.6.2 + Java 17:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
```

**What I want:**

```
{
 "status": "OK",
 "result": {
   "username": "johndoe"
   }
 }
```

**What I get:**

```
{
   "username":  "johndoe"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using the OperationCustomizer interface:

```
@Configuration
class ApiDocsOperationCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {

@Override
public Operation customize(Operation operation,
                           HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
    final Content content = operation.getResponses().get("200").getContent();
    content.keySet().forEach(mediaTypeKey -> {
        final MediaType mediaType = content.get(mediaTypeKey);
        mediaType.schema(this.customizeSchema(mediaType.getSchema()));
    });
    return operation;
}

private Schema<?> customizeSchema(final Schema<?> objSchema) {
    final Schema<?> wrapperSchema = new Schema<>();
    wrapperSchema.addProperties("success", new BooleanSchema()._default(true));
    wrapperSchema.addProperties("result", objSchema);
    return wrapperSchema;
}}
```